# Why is redux better than a simple object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am learning Redux. As I understand, Redux in React helps us to manage state of React app. But why can't I just use empty object to hold all necessary state changes?

For example, I have root component with two subcomponents.

```
<App>
   <Label/>
   <Button/>
</App>
```

Inside Label I have state {numb: 1} and one function, that increase numb

```
increase() {
    setState(prevState => {
        return {numb: prevState.numb + 1}
    });
}
```

On top of this component I import Store.js file, that exports empty object, that I use to store all my change state functions.

```
import Store from './Store'
```

And in the constructor of Label, I just assign function from that component

```
Store.plusOne = this.increase
```

That helps me to import Store file inside Button component and use increase function to increase Label's numb property.

```
<button onClick={Store.increase}>Plus One to Label's numb</button>
```

So what is the point to use Redux, if I can store any state change function in a separate object?

Comment: How do your components "listen" for changes in the store? Or is your store just a collection of functions - it does not store the state data too?

Comment: What if you wanted something else to react to that state change, another component, or maybe some localStorage store.  Redux gives you a subscriber pattern, so you have one source of truth.  Data can only be mutated by dispatching an action, a simple object could be mutated in multiple, and sometimes not so obvious places.

Comment: Also mutating the state should only be done through serializable actions to allow for time traveling through changes. This is a huge benefit when you try do debug your application. It is not by accident that redux is being used by a huge majority of decently sized react applications.

Comment: For Sergiu Paraschiv: When I import Store and use function from another component, it executes the same way, as it would be executed inside the component. Yes, it is just collection of functions, so all data and logic are placed inside components or fetched from API.

For Keith: For another components to execute the function, they can import the Store and execute the function. For situations, where my concept of Store file doesn't help, it is possible to use the file alongside with Redux or another tool.

Comment: For trixn: Yes, you right. It doesn't help for debugging. But probably (i don't sure) it can be used for simple projects or parts inside complex apps, to keep component communication simple.

Thanks all for your attention.  You help me learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same feeling when I started with Redux a few years ago. "Man, this seems overly complicated". But then I realised while not using redux that I was doing the same things but less efficient and more error prone when doing things "manually".

Redux comes with a few powerful helper functions. The first one is `connect` which helps you to get those state properties into your components. You can literally connect your components to your state. You don't have to worry about anything else, change the state in a single place and watch the changes flow through your application.

Because you "plop" (yes, a technical term...cough) all the properties you need for that component from your state onto the `props` of your component you automatically get that the component refreshes when your state changes. Even while using pure functions or a `PureComponent` which might be very good for performance.

You can see it like this. If you want React + Redux to automatically reflow your application: use Redux. If you manually want to update a object and manually force your application to reflow, use a custom state object.

That being said, I think redux makes sense in bigger applications where multiple components depend on the same state. If you just have a single piece of data rendered in a single component or a demo app with a simple button click you might as well keep it simple with a small object.